# How do I get the mean of a list of numbers

Tags: python

Need a code to calculate the mean of a list of numbers entered by users that stops when “stop” is entered, but am unsure how to use 'while' to continue the loop and 'if' to end.

```
number = int(input("Enter an integer"))
n=1
while number>0:
    number+=int(input("Enter an integer"))
    n+=1
    print(number/n)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the number you just entered separate from your running sum.

```
number = int(input("Enter an integer"))
n = 1
total = number
while number > 0:
    number = int(input("Enter an integer"))
    n += 1
    total += number
    print(total/n)
```

This is simpler if you use an infinite loop with an explicit `break` statement, so that you don't need to repeat the call to `input` in two places.

```
total = 0

while True:
    number = int(input("Enter an integer"))
    if number <= 0:
        break
    n += 1
    total += number
    print(number/n)
```